# Excel JavaScript API - How to change calculation mode

Tags: javascript, office-js, excel-addins

This is my code:

```
Excel.Application.set({calculationMode: "Manual"});
```

But the compiler throws

> TS2339: Property 'set' does not exist on type 'typeof Application'.

What is the api to change calculation mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to set the calculation mode in a context like in the following code.

```js
async function setCalculationMode() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    context.application.calculationMode = Excel.CalculationMode.manual;
    await context.sync();
  });
}
```